# Calling one form from another form in same page in Spring MVC

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring, spring-mvc

I have a html page in a Spring MVC project, Page1.html. This page has list of items that are shown whenever page is loaded. It has other form(1,2,3..) too actually in my case **Page1.html** have 6 different form. From the first form when user selects some fields and then presses button "showForm" it calls jQuery to show second form but it's not working for me but once i use simple form it's working fine for me, but i have to use Spring form tld here is my code snippet--

```
    **HTML**
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="add">
<div class="form-group">
    <form:select path="Type" class="form-control" id="Choice">
        <form:option value="${null}">--Select Type--</form:option>
        <form:options items="${TypeList}" itemLabel="Type"itemValue="TypeId" />
    </form:select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <form:select path="Language" class="form-control" id="Language">
       <form:option value="{null}">--Select Language--</form:option>
       <form:options items="${languageList}" itemLabel="languages"
                                    itemValue="languages" />
    </form:select>
 </div>
<div>
     <form:button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="showForm">Show
                        Form</form:button>
</div>
</form:form>
```

**And in same page the second form looks like**

```
<div id="singleChoiceSingleLanguage">
  <form:form method="post" modelAttribute="add">
     <div id="show">
        <form:textarea id="Paragraph" path="eParagraph" />
            <script>
                    CKEDITOR.replace('Paragraph');
            </script>
    </div>
 </form:form>
</div>
```

and my JQuery code looks like --

```
$('#showForm').on('click',function(){
      if((($('#Choice').val() == 'Single Choice')|| ($('#Choice').val() == 'Multiple Choice')) && (($('#Language').val() == 'ENGLISH') || ($('#Language').val() == 'HINDI'))){

          $('#singleChoiceSingleLanguage').show();
      }
      else{
       $('#singleChoiceSingleLanguage').hide();
      }
```

these above code is not working for me.. Any one can help me. If any refactoring is needed in design please tell me. Thanks

Comment: Where do you have `id=singleChoiceSingleLanguage` in your html?

Comment: @Optio question edited have a look it.